# How to display screen on text with turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make text display on the screen, in a turtle screen. As best as I can tell, that involves writing with *onpresskey* but, if that's the case, I don't know what to input as the 'key' (hence the question marks in my code).

```
import turtle


class Graphics:
  def __init__(self):
    # window
    self.win = turtle.Screen()
    self.win.setup(width=1280, height=800)
    self.win.bgcolor('DimGrey')
    self.onkeypress(self.text_xy, ???)
    self.listen()
    # tracer #1
    self.tracer = turtle.Turtle()
    self.tracer.hideturtle()
    self.tracer.speed(0)

...

  def text_xy(self):
         self.win.onkeypress(self.tracer.write(???, font=("Arial", 12, "bold",), /
         align="left"))

 Graphics()


 turtle.mainloop()
```

The only way I can think of doing it would be to do it for every single valid keys (which would be all letters plus 0-9). There's got to be a smarter way to about it.

Comment: There's not enough code in your question to help you. Please [edit] it and provide more, preferably a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @martineau: That should be it, now. Unless I missed something? The code won't run because I don't know what to put in the ??? but I figured that was clearer than leaving that blank.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated version of my original answer. It still does things in the somewhat hacky manner that it did before, but now does so in a slightly less-ugly way, with no inspecting of stack frames involved—thanks to some constructive comments by @Dan D.

This version accomplishes what you need *without* using the `turtle.onkeypress()` event handler to register a function for handling keypresses. Instead it attaches its own handler directly to the lower-level underlying tkinter `Canvas` object. At that level all event handler functions receive an `event` argument automatically and this can be examined to see if it's a keyboard event of interest.

**Caveat:** It's possible that not using `turtle`'s `onkeypress()` has some side-effects since this circumvents the way the module normally processes events, although I didn't observe any, but, depending on exactly what you're doing, your mileage may vary.

```
import turtle

class Graphics:
    def __init__(self):
        # window
        self.win = turtle.Screen()
        self.win.setup(width=1280, height=800)
        self.win.bgcolor('DimGrey')
        self.font = ("Arial", 12, "bold",)
        self.win.cv.bind('<KeyPress>', self.text_xy)
        self.win.listen()
        # tracer #1
        self.tracer = turtle.Turtle()
        self.tracer.hideturtle()
        self.tracer.speed(0)

    def text_xy(self, event):
        if event.char != '':  # Not a modifier?
            self.tracer.write(event.char, move=True, font=self.font,
                              align="left")

Graphics()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Call `self.win.cv.bind("<KeyPress>", eventfun)` directly. The access `self.win.cv` violates the law of Demeter. But I would suggest that it is better than inspecting stack frames and turtle is unlikely to change from using a tk canvas.

Comment: @Dan: Perhaps I don't understand your comment, but one can't call `self.win.cv.bind("<KeyPress>", eventfun)` directly because `eventfun` is in a function nested inside the `TurtleScreenBase._onkeypress()` method.

Comment: You replace `eventfun` with the name of your event handling method. The name was not to refer to the function defined in the body of `onkeypress` but rather to say that you call `self.win.cv.bind` directly.

Comment: @Dan: OK, now I understand...thanks. Good idea...much clearner than my original answer, so I've changed it accordingly. Your approach may have it's own unintended side-effects, but that's a trade-off that may have to be made.

Answer (score 2):

Writing text on the turtle screen is not inherently intertwined with `onpresskey`.  You can simply write text to the screen, write text when a key is clicked, write text when a mouse button is clicked, etc.  Here's some example code that does all three:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ("Arial", 14, "bold")

class Graphics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.screen.setup(width=1280, height=800)
        self.screen.listen()

        self.turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
        self.turtle.speed('fastest')

    def text_at_xy(self, x, y, text):
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(x, y)
        self.turtle.write(text, font=FONT)

    def text_onkey(self, x, y, text, key):
        self.screen.onkey(lambda x=x, y=y, text=text: self.text_at_xy(x, y, text), key)

    def text_onmouseclick(self, text):
        self.screen.onclick(lambda x, y, text=text: self.text_at_xy(x, y, text))


graphics = Graphics()

graphics.text_at_xy(100, 100, "Static Text")  # just print text at location

graphics.text_onkey(-100, -100, "On Key Text", "j")  # print text at location when you type "j"

graphics.text_onmouseclick("On Mouse Click Text")  # print text whereever mouse is clicked

graphics.screen.mainloop()
```

Building on @martineau's work and @DanD's comments, we could type continuously by doing:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ("Arial", 14, "bold")

class Graphics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.screen.setup(width=1280, height=800)
        self.screen.listen()

        self.turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
        self.turtle.speed('fastest')

        self.screen.cv.bind("<KeyPress>", lambda event: self.text_xy(event.char))

    def text_xy(self, char):
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.write(char, move=True, font=FONT)

graphics = Graphics()

graphics.screen.mainloop()
```

Note that we're dropping below the turtle API into the tkinter underpinnings to implement this.